# na.spline() only prints the output but does not store it to be exported

Tags: r

Respected members,
I have some time series data which has missing values marked as NA. I tried to interpolate NAs using `na.spline()` and it was a sucessfull attempt. The function interpolated all the NAs and printed them on the console. Now the problem is that it does not store it in a variable so I export the data set to other software (excel or stata).

I have tried to create a new variable and tried to store the output of na.spline in it but not successful.

```
 #install.packages('zoo')
    require(zoo)
    carry <- read_excel("C:/Users/new/Desktop/carry.xlsx")
    missing <- (carry$colozn)

 interpolated_output <- na.spline(missing)
```

I expected that `interpolated_output` would contain all the data with NAs replaced so I would be able to export it but that does not happen. However if I write only `na.spline(missing)` it prints the result but does not store. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please add some more details. Specifically, please add a sample of `carry` by using `dput(carry)`

Comment: Dear Nelson, I have imported a file named carry.xlsx, which contains only one column. colozn is the column heading and it contains 18841 observations (rows) and 1984 of them are NA. I want to interpolate these NAs using cubic spline and then the dataset exported back to Excel or stata.   dput(carry) prints the following. Waiting for help. Thanks                                                     
 "254.3", "260.10000000000002", "247.5", "263.10000000000002", 
"271.8", "285.5","261.1000000000
"258.2", "254.3", "263.10000000000002", "259.2", "261.10000000000002", 
"NA", "NA", "NA",

Comment: The warning message i get is                                                                                                             interpolated_output <- na.spline(missing)
Warning message:
In xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Might be you are confusing something. I think the code you posted should work. The warning message you posted "Warning message: In xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : NAs introduced by coercion" usually appears when you try to plot something and shouldn't be related to the na replacement part. Did you post your complete code?

Comment: Stats0007 you are right code was working and it was interpolating missing values despite the warning and also printing the data on the console. My problem was that i wanted to append the newly created variable that contains interpolated values to the data frame, so i could export it to excel or some other software. However i found the solution and it was simple.                                                     Carry <- carry$interpolated_output, it appended the output to the dataframe.                Thanks for your response.